# Circa 60's or 70's film about a woman who steals a dead womans ring and the dead woman rises and comes floating after her

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I have been searching for this film for decades. I believe it is late 60's early 70's.  As a woman lies dead, another woman, possibly an attendant or relative, steals a ring from her finger. Afterwards the woman rises up and floats after her to get her ring back. This film scared me stiff, unusually scary for its time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be Black Sabbath (1963), in particular the third story, named "The Drop of Water".

From Wikipedia:

> In London, England, **Nurse** Helen Chester (Jacqueline Pierreux) is called to a large house to prepare the corpse of an elderly medium for her burial. As she dresses the body, she notices a **sapphire ring** on its finger. Chester steals it, [...] Chester finds the woman's corpse lying in her bed. **It rises and floats toward her.**

Comment: you are spot on here.  I don't have a clue as to where to find this movie, anyone have any ideas?  This is one scary show!

Comment: @Fey Ray according to [this website](http://www.flixlist.co/titles/60001693), you can find it on Netflix.

Comment: Update--I found this movie on Amazon Prime !!  They have a really good selection and is well worth the 50 a year !